# Run FFMPEG in an Async Subprocess then Kill after condition complete?

Tags: python, asynchronous, ffmpeg, subprocess, python-asyncio

I am struggling to get this correct. I have a sample piece of code here:

```
import asyncio
import signal
import os
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen


async def recScreen():
    cmd = 'ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i desktop output.mkv'
    process = Popen(cmd)
    await asyncio.sleep(15)
    print("Done sleep")
    process.terminate()
    return 0

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(recScreen())
loop.close()
```

The whole idea is that, after a condition is met (e.g. sleeping after 15 seconds), we can tell ffmpeg to gracefully stop recording and close.

However, I have yet to find a method that does that. In this example, and most examples using process.terminate() and process.kill(), the process ends abruptly without letting ffmpeg do a clean exit. Attempting to add await to process throws an error since it cannot be awaited.

Using a sample piece like:

```
    process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(
        command, stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE, stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE
    )
```

and then

```
await process.terminate()
```

Throws a NotImplementedError.

I am confused and not sure how I should go about. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: I assume you are running on Windows. On that OS the subprocess module (as well as the equivalent asyncio one) use the same implementation for `terminate` and `kill`, so a graceful termination (like sending the `SIGTERM` signal on a Unix-like OS) is not supported. You should check whether `ffmpeg` supports some way to be gracefully terminated, and use that.

Comment: The `NotImplementedError` comes from the `SelectorEventLoop` being used by default on Windows. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/asyncio-eventloops.html#asyncio.ProactorEventLoop) for instructions how to switch to the proactor loop. That should fix the `NotImplementedError`, but is unlikely to fix the issue you had with `subprocess`, which is that ffmpeg will be killed without letting it clean up.